# TFS2010: How to link a WorkItem to a ChangeSet

Tags: c#

I would like to programatically link WorkItems to Changesets.

At the moment I am already creating work items from my c# code and saving them to the TFS. The code looks as follows:

```
WorkItem item = new WorkItem(project.WorkItemTypes["CustomItem"]);            
item.Fields["CustomField1"].Value = someValue;
item.Fields["CustomField2"].Value = someValue;
item.Fields["CustomField3"].Value = someValue;
item.Validate();
item.Save();
```

This part of the code works fine. Now I would like to associate the newly created work item to an existing changeset. I am getting the changeset using:

```
VersionControlServer service = collection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
Changeset changeset = service.GetChangeset(123123, true, true);
```

However, I can only iterate through the existing work items. I cannot add a new work item to this changeset. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out how to do this by trail-and-error method:

```
WorkItemStore store = new WorkItemStore(collection);
Changeset changeset = service.GetChangeset(123, true, true);

WorkItem item = new WorkItem(project.WorkItemTypes["CustomItem"]);     
item.Links.Add(new ExternalLink(store.RegisteredLinkTypes[ArtifactLinkIds.Changeset], changeset.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri));       
item.Fields["CustomField1"].Value = someValue;
item.Fields["CustomField2"].Value = someValue;
item.Fields["CustomField3"].Value = someValue;
item.Validate();
item.Save();
```

I hope this will help someone else in the future! :)

Christian

Comment: Thank - a subtle tweak for me;
`code`_newLink = new ExternalLink(_wis.RegisteredLinkTypes[ArtifactLinkIds.VersionedItem], _latestItem.ArtifactUriLatestItemVersion.AbsoluteUri);