# Associating existing unassociated changesets with workitem in TFS

Tags: associations, changeset, tfs-workitem

I know there're powerful TFS command line tools from TFS Power tools that provide much more that can be achieved through Visual Studio integrated capabilities.

I have several changesets that aren't associated with any workitem. I would like to create a new workitem and associate these existing changesets with it.

**Is this possible?** I don't see any particular reason why not, but it depends whether command line tools provide such functionality.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sure you can associate a work item to an existing changeset. You can do that directly in the Visual Studio IDE. Here's how:

First open the work item - and select the *All Links* tab:

[image: Work item details]

Then click on *Link to* and select the changeset and click *Ok*:

[image: Select changeset here]

Comment: Thanks Morten. I apparently thought this is a seldom executed task and wouldn't be included in VS integrated feature set (like unshelving to different branches). Thanks for this visual guideline.

Comment: On a (checked-in) changeset you can to two things: Change linked work items and change the check-in comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, read bellow.

This can be achieved from workitems links section, in your definition i don't see reason why you would want to use something else. 
If you are interested in some bulk solution, then Tfs has full-fledged API any tool will likely using it as well.

Following covers your case in api:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3280.tfs-2010-api-create-workitems-bugs.aspx
[TFS2010: How to link a WorkItem to a ChangeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333505/tfs2010-how-to-link-a-workitem-to-a-changeset), you can use VersionControlServer.QueryHistory method to get changesets you need

For powershell this covers item creation:
http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/automating-work-item-creation-in-tfs-2010-with-powershell-continued/

Comment: Thanks. I apparently wasn't looking good enough to see it in IDE. +1 for the bulk guideline although I won't be needing it. Somebody else might.